# collision detection with lots of objects

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection

I have around several hundreds of moving objects within screen at the given time, plus a thousand+ stationary objects. For simplicity, you can think of it as a billiard game with damn lots of balls :) Some of them are stayin still, some others are moving at all sorts of speeds to all sorts of different directions. I need coll detection each time each ball bumps into another ball. What is the best method, considering performance and, well, programming simplicity? I'm talking algorithm only, I guess I can implement it myself, tho suggestions on implementation are welcome as well ;)

Language is C#, XNA 3.1, 2D graphics, target platform is Windows only (if that matters). Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345838/ball-to-ball-collision-detection-and-handling).