# How to handle ball to ball collision with trigonometry instead of vectors?

Tags: graphics, collision-detection, physics, trigonometry

I am making a simplified version of the ball physics app found at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345838/ball-to-ball-collision-detection-and-handling).  I gained a lot from reading through the code and links provided at that question, but in my program I do not use vectors, I just update the coordinates of my balls (each of which has a random angle and speed) with trigonometry functions when they hit the walls.

There is info all over the place for how to handle ball to ball collisions **without** trigonometry, but I have found none that explain how it can be done **with** trigonometry.

**--EDIT 9/13/2010--**

Success... kind of... I got done what I wanted to do, but I was unable to do it how I wanted.  If there is a way to calculate ball to ball collisions without the use of vectors it has eluded me.  Even so, vectors do seem to be an easier way to handle collisions of all types... I just wish I would have known that when I started my program... would have saved me two or three days of work :)  All the code for my (complete?) program is below.  I added some neat features like shadows and a decreasing ball radius which really lets you see the difference in the mass of two balls when a big ball hits a small ball.  In total there are five class files, `AddLogic.java`, `Ball.java`, `BallBuilder.java`, `MouseEventHandler.java`, and `Vector2D.java`.

**AddLogic.java**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AddLogic implements Runnable {//Make AddLogic a runnable task.

    private BallBuilder ballBuilder;
    private BufferStrategy strategy;
    private static ArrayList objectsToDraw = new ArrayList();
    private int floorHeight = 33;

    public AddLogic(BallBuilder ballBuilder, BufferStrategy strategy) {
        this.ballBuilder = ballBuilder;
        this.strategy = strategy;
    }

    private void logic(BallBuilder ballBuilder, BufferStrategy strategy) {
        this.ballBuilder = ballBuilder;
        this.strategy = strategy;

        while (true) {//Main loop. Draws all objects on screen and calls update methods.
            Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) strategy.getDrawGraphics();//Creates the Graphics2D object g and uses it with the double buffer.
            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, ballBuilder.getWidth(), ballBuilder.getHeight());//Draw the wall.
            g.setColor(Color.lightGray);
            g.fillRect(0, ballBuilder.getHeight() - floorHeight, ballBuilder.getWidth(), floorHeight);//Draw the floor.
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawLine(0, ballBuilder.getHeight() - floorHeight, ballBuilder.getWidth(), ballBuilder.getHeight() - floorHeight);//Draw the line between the wall and floor.

            if (objectsToDrawIsEmpty() == true) {//If no balls have been made display message telling users how to make new ball.
                g.setColor(Color.red);
                g.drawString("Click Mouse For New Ball", (ballBuilder.getWidth() / 2) - 70, ballBuilder.getHeight() / 2);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < objectsToDraw.size(); i++) {//Draw shadows for all balls.
                Ball ball = (Ball) objectsToDraw.get(i);
                g.setColor(Color.darkGray);
                g.fillOval(
                        (int) ball.ballPosition.getX() - (int) ((ball.ballPosition.getY() / (350 / ball.getBallRadius())) / 2),
                        ballBuilder.getHeight() - (floorHeight / 2) - (int) ((ball.ballPosition.getY() / (1250 / ball.getBallRadius())) / 2),
                        (int) ball.ballPosition.getY() / (350 / ball.getBallRadius()),
                        (int) ball.ballPosition.getY() / (1250 / ball.getBallRadius()));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < objectsToDraw.size(); i++) {//Draw all balls by looping through them and checking for any vector or collision updates that need to be made.
                Ball ball = (Ball) objectsToDraw.get(i);
                g.setColor(ball.getBallColor());
                g.fillOval(
                        (int) ball.ballPosition.getX() - ball.getBallRadius(),
                        (int) ball.ballPosition.getY() - ball.getBallRadius(),
                        ball.getBallRadius() * 2,
                        ball.getBallRadius() * 2);

                vectorUpdate(ball);//Update ball vector coordinates.

                collisionCheck(ball);//Check ball to ball and ball to wall collisions.

            }

            if (MouseEventHandler.mouseEventCheck() == true) {// Creates a new ball when mouse is clicked.
                Ball ball = new Ball(ballBuilder);
                objectsToDraw.add(ball); //Adds the new ball to the array list.
                MouseEventHandler.mouseEventUpdate(); //Resets the mouse click event to false.

            }

            g.dispose();//To aid Java in garbage collection.
            strategy.show();//Show all graphics drawn on the buffer.

            try {//Try to make thread sleep for 5ms.  Results in a frame rate of 200FPS.
                Thread.sleep(5);
            }

            catch (Exception e) {//Catch any exceptions if try fails.

            }
        }
    }

    private void vectorUpdate(Ball ball) {//Update the ball vector based upon the ball's current position and its velocity.

        ball.ballPosition.setX(ball.ballPosition.getX() + ball.ballVelocity.getX());
        ball.ballPosition.setY(ball.ballPosition.getY() + ball.ballVelocity.getY());

    }

    private void collisionCheck(Ball ball) {//Check for ball to wall collisions. Call check for ball to ball collisions at end of method.

        if (ball.ballPosition.getX() - ball.getBallRadius() < 0) {//Check for ball to left wall collision.
            ball.ballPosition.setX(ball.getBallRadius());
            ball.ballVelocity.setX(-(ball.ballVelocity.getX()));
            ball.decreaseBallRadius(ball);//Decrease ball radius by one pixel. Called on left, top, and right walls, but not bottom because it looks weird watching shadow get smaller during bottom bounce.

        }

        else if (ball.ballPosition.getX() + ball.getBallRadius() > ballBuilder.getWidth()) {//Check for ball to right wall collision.
            ball.ballPosition.setX(ballBuilder.getWidth() - ball.getBallRadius());
            ball.ballVelocity.setX(-(ball.ballVelocity.getX()));
            ball.decreaseBallRadius(ball);//Decrease ball radius by one pixel. Called on left, top, and right walls, but not bottom because it looks weird watching shadow get smaller during bottom bounce.
        }

        if (ball.ballPosition.getY() - ball.getBallRadius() < 0) {//Check for ball to top wall collision.
            ball.ballPosition.setY(ball.getBallRadius());
            ball.ballVelocity.setY(-(ball.ballVelocity.getY()));
            ball.decreaseBallRadius(ball);//Decrease ball radius by one pixel. Called on left, top, and right walls, but not bottom because it looks weird watching shadow get smaller during bottom bounce.
        }

        else if (ball.ballPosition.getY() + ball.getBallRadius() + (floorHeight / 2) > ballBuilder.getHeight()) {//Check for ball to bottom wall collision.  Floor height is accounted for to give the appearance that ball is bouncing in the center of the floor strip.
            ball.ballPosition.setY(ballBuilder.getHeight() - ball.getBallRadius() - (floorHeight / 2));
            ball.ballVelocity.setY(-(ball.ballVelocity.getY()));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToDraw.size(); i++) {//Check to see if a ball is touching any other balls by looping through all balls and checking their positions.
            Ball otherBall = (Ball) objectsToDraw.get(i);

            if (ball != otherBall && Math.sqrt(Math.pow(ball.ballPosition.getX() - otherBall.ballPosition.getX(), 2.0) + Math.pow(ball.ballPosition.getY() - otherBall.ballPosition.getY(), 2.0)) < ball.getBallRadius() + otherBall.getBallRadius()) {
                resolveBallToBallCollision(ball, otherBall);//If the ball is hitting another ball calculate the new vectors based on the variables of the balls involved.
            }

        }

    }

    private void resolveBallToBallCollision(Ball ball, Ball otherBall) {//Calculate the new vectors after ball to ball collisions.
        Vector2D delta = (ball.ballPosition.subtract(otherBall.ballPosition));//Difference between the position of the two balls involved in the collision.
        float deltaLength = delta.getLength();//The (x, y) of the delta squared.

        Vector2D minimumTranslationDistance = delta.multiply(((ball.getBallRadius() + otherBall.getBallRadius()) - deltaLength) / deltaLength);//The minimum distance the balls should move apart once they.

        float ballInverseMass = 1 / ball.getBallMass();//half the ball mass.
        float otherBallInverseMass = 1 / otherBall.getBallMass();//half the other ball mass.

        ball.ballPosition = ball.ballPosition.add(minimumTranslationDistance.multiply(ballInverseMass / (ballInverseMass + otherBallInverseMass)));//Calculate the new position of the ball.
        otherBall.ballPosition = otherBall.ballPosition.subtract(minimumTranslationDistance.multiply(otherBallInverseMass / (ballInverseMass + otherBallInverseMass)));//Calculate the new position of the other ball.

        Vector2D impactVelocity = (ball.ballVelocity.subtract(otherBall.ballVelocity));//Find the veloicity of the impact based upon the velocities of the two balls involved.
        float normalizedImpactVelocity = impactVelocity.dot(minimumTranslationDistance.normalize());//

        if (normalizedImpactVelocity > 0.0f) {//Returns control to calling object if ball and other ball are intersecting, but moving away from each other.
            return;
        }

        float restitution = 2.0f;//The constraint representing friction. A value of 2.0 is 0 friction, a value smaller than 2.0 is more friction, and a value over 2.0 is negative friction.

        float i = (-(restitution) * normalizedImpactVelocity) / (ballInverseMass + otherBallInverseMass);
        Vector2D impulse = minimumTranslationDistance.multiply(i);

        ball.ballVelocity = ball.ballVelocity.add(impulse.multiply(ballInverseMass));//Change the velocity of the ball based upon its mass.
        otherBall.ballVelocity = otherBall.ballVelocity.subtract(impulse.multiply(otherBallInverseMass));//Change the velocity of the other ball based upon its mass.
    }

    public static boolean objectsToDrawIsEmpty() {//Checks to see if there are any balls to draw.
        boolean empty = false;
        if (objectsToDraw.isEmpty()) {
            empty = true;
        }

        return empty;

    }

    public void run() {//Runs the AddLogic instance logic in a new thread.
        logic(ballBuilder, strategy);
    }
}
```

**Ball.java**

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Ball {

    private int ballRadius;
    private float ballMass;
    public Vector2D ballPosition = new Vector2D();
    public Vector2D ballVelocity = new Vector2D();
    private Color ballColor;

    public Ball(BallBuilder ballBuilder) {//Construct a new ball.
        this.ballRadius = 75;//When ball is created make its radius 75 pixels.
        this.ballMass = ((float)(4 / 3 * Math.PI * Math.pow(ballRadius, 3.0)));//When ball is created make its mass that the volume of a sphere the same size.
        this.ballPosition.set(ballRadius, ballBuilder.getHeight() - ballRadius);//When ball is created make its starting coordinates the bottom left hand corner of the screen.
        this.ballVelocity.set(randomVelocity(), randomVelocity());//When ball is created make its (x, y) velocity a random value between 0 and 2.

        if (AddLogic.objectsToDrawIsEmpty() == true) {//If the ball being created is the first ball, make it blue, otherwise pick a random color.
            this.ballColor = Color.blue;
        } else {
            this.ballColor = randomColor();
        }

    }

    public void decreaseBallRadius(Ball ball){//Decrease the ball radius.
        if(ball.getBallRadius() <= 15){//If the ball radius is less than or equal to 15 return control to calling object, else continue.
            return;
        }

        ball.setBallRadius(ball.getBallRadius() - 1);//Decrease the ball radius by 1 pixel.
        ball.setBallMass((float)(4 / 3 * Math.PI * Math.pow(ballRadius, 3.0)));//Recalcualte the mass based on the new radius.

    }

    public int getBallRadius() {
        return ballRadius;
    }

    public float getBallMass(){
        return ballMass;
    }

    public Color getBallColor() {
        return ballColor;
    }

    private void setBallRadius(int newBallRadius) {
        this.ballRadius = newBallRadius;
    }

    private void setBallMass(float newBallMass){
        this.ballMass = newBallMass;
    }

    private float randomVelocity() {//Generate a random number between 0 and 2 for the (x, y) velocity of a ball.
        float speed = (float)(Math.random() * 2);
        return speed;
    }

    private Color randomColor() {//Generate a random color for a new ball based on the generation of a random red, green, and blue value.
        int red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        int green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        ballColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
        return ballColor;
    }

}
```

**BallBuilder.java**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BallBuilder extends Canvas{
    private int frameHeight = 600;
    private int frameWidth = 800;

    private static BufferStrategy strategy;//Create a buffer strategy named strategy.

    public BallBuilder(){
        setIgnoreRepaint(true);//Tell OS that we will handle any repainting manually.
        setBounds(0,0,frameWidth,frameHeight);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Bouncing Balls");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(frameWidth, frameHeight));
        panel.add(this);

        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        addMouseListener(new MouseEventHandler());

        createBufferStrategy(2);//Create a double buffer for smooth graphics.
    strategy = getBufferStrategy();//Apply the double buffer to the buffer strategy named strategy.

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BallBuilder ballBuilder = new BallBuilder(); // Creates a new ball builder.
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();//Creates a thread executor that uses a single thread.
        executor.execute(new AddLogic(ballBuilder, strategy));//Executes the runnable task AddLogic on the previously created thread.

    }

}
```

**MouseEventHandler.java**

```
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MouseEventHandler extends MouseAdapter{

    private static boolean mouseClicked = false;

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){//If either of the mouse buttons is pressed the mouse clicked variable is set to true.
        mouseClicked = true;
    }

    public static void mouseEventUpdate(){//When called, sets the mouse clicked variable back to false.
        mouseClicked = false;
    }

    public static boolean mouseEventCheck(){//Returns the state of the mouse clicked variable.
        if(mouseClicked){
            return true;
        }

        else{
            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

**Vector2D**

```
public class Vector2D {//A class that takes care of ball position and speed vectors.

    private float x;
    private float y;

    public Vector2D() {
        this.setX(0);
        this.setY(0);
    }

    public Vector2D(float x, float y) {
        this.setX(x);
        this.setY(y);
    }

    public void set(float x, float y) {
        this.setX(x);
        this.setY(y);
    }

    public void setX(float x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(float y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public float getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public float getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public float dot(Vector2D v2) {//Speciality method used during calculations of ball to ball collisions.
        float result = 0.0f;
        result = this.getX() * v2.getX() + this.getY() * v2.getY();
        return result;
    }

    public float getLength() {
        return (float) Math.sqrt(getX() * getX() + getY() * getY());
    }

    public Vector2D add(Vector2D v2) {
        Vector2D result = new Vector2D();
        result.setX(getX() + v2.getX());
        result.setY(getY() + v2.getY());
        return result;
    }

    public Vector2D subtract(Vector2D v2) {
        Vector2D result = new Vector2D();
        result.setX(this.getX() - v2.getX());
        result.setY(this.getY() - v2.getY());
        return result;
    }

    public Vector2D multiply(float scaleFactor) {
        Vector2D result = new Vector2D();
        result.setX(this.getX() * scaleFactor);
        result.setY(this.getY() * scaleFactor);
        return result;
    }

    public Vector2D normalize() {//Speciality method used during calculations of ball to ball collisions.
        float length = getLength();
        if (length != 0.0f) {
            this.setX(this.getX() / length);
            this.setY(this.getY() / length);
        } else {
            this.setX(0.0f);
            this.setY(0.0f);
        }

        return this;
    }

}
```

Comment: Vectors are trigonometry beasts in disguise. It's a way to shorten the equations, writing one eq for all dimensions at once.

Comment: I see that now, the thing is that my program is nearly complete and I do all my updates with basic trigonometry, if I introduce what I have recently learned about vectors then all the collision detection I have coded thus far will be for nothing.  At this point it looks like I am going to try and overlap the two, using the collision detection I have already but using vectors just for ball to ball collisions.  Seems like a waste (I would have used vectors for everything if I knew then what I know now) but unless someone knows how to exclude vectors then I am at a loss.

Comment: @typoknig I guess it should be easy to reuse your code. Please post a method or function already running, and we could try to help you with some hints.

Comment: @typoknig Thanks for posting the code. I think there is a lot to improve since, for example, UpdateX should be only one or two lines of code (essentially newX = oldX + speed * Math.Cos(angle)). But there are a few vars in the classes that you did not include that are not clear to me, So I don't want to risk a wrong answer that will drain a lot of time from both of us. Please try to post the full code. Tnx! ... (And post a comment with the text "@belisarius" so I'll get the SO message alarm)

Comment: @belisarius, question has been updated.  Also thanks for letting me know about the `@` sign.  I put it in usually just because that is what I saw people doing, but I didn't realize it was what alerted the user.  Is there a page of other such conventions for SO usage?

Comment: @typoknig I got some hints in meta. Read the first answer in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11098/reply-to-comment-feature-request

Comment: @typoknig This is what you should implement http://members.shaw.ca/mathematica/ahabTutorials/2dCollision.html (the math here is bad, but you'll get an idea) do not copy those equations ....

Comment: @belisarius I updated the code in my question to the new vectorized version.  Check it out... added some neat features.

Comment: @typoknig Nice work! Two suggestions: 1) Try to realize that this code is equivalent to my answers (the hidden thing is that the formulas with Math.cos and Math.sin are mathematically equivalent to your new Update methods) and 2) add a very small random pertubation to the angle at each bounce to get rid of nasty irreal looking cycles. That said ... congrats!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The speed angle changes when the ball bounces, you should change it after each bounce.**

[image]

Also, as you'll see later, the speed VALUE (called "modulus") also changes when two balls collide.

EDIT:::

It seems to me that you are accelerating the balls

The

```
int x = (int) (ball.getBallTempX() + 
              (ball.getBallPathLength() * Math.cos(ball.getBallAngle())));
```

Seems to correspond to

```
int x = (int) (ball.getBallTempX() + 
              (ball.getBallSpeed() * Math.cos(ball.getBallAngle())));
```

And the same for "y"

Am I right?

**Edit 2::**

In fact, you don't need the TempX,TempY,PreviousCenterX and PreviousCenterY either.

Try these methods

```
private int xCoordinateUpdate(Ball ball) {

   int x = (int) (ball.getBallCenterX()+ (ball.Speed() 
                                      * Math.cos(ball.getBallAngle())));

return x;
```

(the same for Y)

**Edit 3 ::**

One more ... :)

What you need is to code is this formula (any other will fail when you attempt to collide balls):

Pseudocode >

BallCenterX = BallCenterX + BallSpeed * Math.cos(angle)

BallCenterY = BallCenterY + BallSpeed * Math.sin(angle)

Forget any "temp" and "old" values. They will impair your ball colliding feature.

Comment: @belisarius No, I am not accelerating the balls.  The `ballPathLength` is just the hypotenuse.  The `ballPathLength` increases by `ballSpeed` every frame, which moves the ball along.  Since I know the `ballAngle` and the hypotenuse (`ballPathLength`) I can use `cos` and `sin` to update the ball coordinates.  Right now a ball remains at it's initial speed all the time, no acceleration.

Comment: @typoknig The ballPathLength means nothing physical. Just get rid of it and replace it for the speed in the formula above. Space = Speed * Time.  No hypotenuse is needed.

Comment: @belisarius if I do that the hypotenuse just stays the same and the ball will not move.  My `ballSpeed` is a range of `1-5` pixels per frame, if I put a number that does not change (like `ballSpeed`) into my triangulation formula above it will always calculate the same thing. You may already know, but if you want to see what I am actually doing in my calculations check this link: http://wright.nasa.gov/airplane/trig.html

Comment: @typoknig It should move. Select the speed from a bigger integer range and try

Comment: @belisarius it is not possible for my balls to move using this formula if the hypotenuse (`ballPathLength`) stays constant. The increase of the hypotenuse (`ballPathLength`) is how I am moving the balls.  Increasing the ball speed (even a lot) and using it in place of `ballPathLength` in the triangulation formula can never move the ball because the value of `ballSpeed` never changes.

Comment: @typoknig  see the Edit 2 above

Comment: @belisarius the `Temp` values were needed so I knew where my hypotenuse start point was when a ball bounced off of a wall.  I meant to delete the `Previous` values before posting my code... they are part of an attempt at vectorization.  `Edit 2` of your answer is not working.  I think that the formula I am using is hindering your efforts to help me.  Any value you put in the place of `ballPathLength` must be  **1.)** a value that increases every frame  **2.)** a value that represents the length of a line **that starts** on one of the edges of the window.

Comment: @belisarius a couple of questions.  First what is `ballSpeed` to you.  For me `ballSpeed` is a small number (less than 5) that represents the number of pixels I want my ball to move every frame. When applying `edit 2` of your answer I did also did `edit 3` but to no avail.  Also, I don't know if it was intentional on your part, the order of operations would mess up the calculation in both `edit 2` and `edit 3` because it would be like saying "my hypotenuse is the speed of my ball".

Comment: @typoknig The hypotenuse concept is misleading. In edit2 I tried to do the same as I did in pseudocede in edit3, because is the only way to go. The speed is exactly that, the number of pixels that your ball will move, but splitted on x and y.

Comment: @typoknig Take a look at the new drawing

Comment: @belisarius during our conversation I have been vectorizing my program and I am nearly complete.  I am right were I was when I asked this question, but using vectors instead of the trig calculations I was using before.  I just need to get the ball to ball collisions taken care of and I think it will be done... working on that now.

Comment: @belisarius I have it all working right now, thanks a lot for your help! I have a bit of cleaning to do in the code, but once I get it finished I will post it (probably tomorrow).  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I'll start this answer and keep editing it step by step until we are done. I'll try to guide you to a "semi-vectorized" version of the program, trying to minimize the effort.
Please keep updating the code as you progress, and commenting on my suggestions.

First, a few things:

In

```
      private double randomBallAngle(){  
         ballAngle = Math.toRadians((Math.random()*90));  
         return ballAngle;  
      }
```

You are working in radians, but in **yCoordinateUpdate** and **yCoordinateUpdate** it seems that you are using the same angle in grads (because you are comparing with 90).

Using radians is easier for all the math involved.

Also, the vars GoingUp, etc are not needed since the speed angle will take care of that.

You may set the initial random angle in the interval (0 ... 2 Pi).

You should change (in fact reflect) the speed angle after each border collission (and afterwards, when we are done, after each inter-ball caollission too).

For this reflection, the laws are:

```
Upper or lower wall:    New Angle =  - OldAngle 

For Right or left wall: New Angle = Pi - OldAngle
```

We'll keep reflections on the vertex for later ...

Comment: @belisarius good catch, I forgot to convert to radians when updating my coordinates.  I have edited the code to fix that.  As for my `GoingUp` and `GoingRight` variables, what do you mean when you say "speed angle"?  I want to point out the speed of a ball is a random value from `1-5`, and that value is how much the hypotenuse (`ballPathLength`) increases every frame.

Comment: @typoknig I am posting a drawing below

Comment: @belisarius though I didn't understand it completely I implemented what you said and it works pretty good.  Cleaned up my code a lot, though balls at a slight angle still stick to the top for some reason.  I am updating the `AddLogic.java` file in my question.

Comment: @belisarius it seems that the balls stick to the top of the screen when they have any angle of 15 degrees or less.

Comment: @typoknig Also ... What is the setPathLength for?

Comment: @typoknig Do they stick to the bottom too?

Comment: @belisarius I set the `ballPathLenght` (the hypotenuse) to `1` every time the ball bounced off the wall so I could correctly calculate my new coordinates.  Every frame I add the `ballSpeed` (lets say 5px) to the `ballPathLenght` (lets say 1).  So every frame the `ballPathLength` is increased by `ballSpeed` until the ball hits a wall, then the `ballPathLenght` is set back to 1 so `cos` and `sin` will calculate the correct coordinates for me.

Comment: @belisarius no, just the top... it is weird (but I have heard of other people having this sticking problem before).

Comment: @typoknig We will deal with the sticky problem after we get rid of the ballPathLength. We need a cleaner code to debug.

Answer (score 2):

[image]