# Javascript ball collision

Tags: javascript, physics, collision-detection, game-physics

I am trying to create a simple javascript game with simple physics.  I can determine when 2 balls are colliding but I have having problems with handling the collision.

Does anyone know of any useful tutorials on this? I've been searching the internet for a couple days but can't seem to find anything.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345838/ball-to-ball-collision-detection-and-handling) help?

Comment: provide code, it'll make it easier for people to solve your question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the UK, this would be A-level maths, so not too advanced. I think the phrase you need is "[elastic collision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision)". That page has some of the formulae you need.

Answer (score 1):

[Physics for JavaScript Games, Animation, and Simulations with HTML5 Canvas](http://www.apress.com/9781430263371)
is a Book all about modeling Physics simulations in JavaScript.

Though this book starts off by introducing the reader to some simple concepts in Physics and how it can be modeled in JavaScript, this books will assume you have some basic knowledge in Physics and know how to program in JavaScript.