# Add collision to HTML5 Canvas

Tags: html, canvas

Hi I have the following HTML5 Canvas app: http://dev.driz.co.uk/app/

When you move the mouse around it will cause the balls to move around, the problem however is that the balls do not react to each other. Instead they just pass over or behind each other.

Looking for some collision detection info for HTML5 Canvas.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ball to Ball Collision - Detection and Handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345838/ball-to-ball-collision-detection-and-handling)

Comment: Do you know of any JavaScript examples for HTML5 Canvas?

Comment: nice snooker game so far. I noticed that your balls exhibit some strange behavior occasionally. strange behavior:
balls get stuck together and spin around one another. Sometimes they pop away from each other, but usually they are just stuck. Do you know why this would occur? I'm not a math wiz, otherwise i'd be more helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Hey everyone. Not sure if you have found this already but I am in the process of creating a snooker game in canvas. My collision detection / handling of the balls is as follows. It's using trig at the moment but could be optimised using some vector math instead. Anyway, you can see the progress with it in action -> [here](http://snooker.stevekane.com.au/demo.html)

This loop runs in my animate function:

```
// checks if the any of the balls have collided with each other
for(i=0;i<ballArray.length;i++)
{
    for(j=i;j<ballArray.length;j++)
    {
        if(j != i)
        {

            if( Math.pow((ballArray[j].x - ballArray[i].x),2) + Math.pow((ballArray[j].y - ballArray[i].y),2) <= (ballArray[i].radius + ballArray[j].radius) * (ballArray[i].radius + ballArray[j].radius))
            {
                dx = ballArray[i].x - ballArray[j].x;
                dy = ballArray[i].y - ballArray[j].y;
                // collision angle is often refered to as the greek character 'phi'
                phi = Math.atan2(dy, dx);

                magnitude_1 = Math.sqrt(ballArray[i].vx * ballArray[i].vx + ballArray[i].vy * ballArray[i].vy);
                magnitude_2 = Math.sqrt(ballArray[j].vx * ballArray[j].vx + ballArray[j].vy * ballArray[j].vy);

                direction_1 = Math.atan2(ballArray[i].vy, ballArray[i].vx);
                direction_2 = Math.atan2(ballArray[j].vy, ballArray[j].vx);

                new_xspeed_1 = magnitude_1 * Math.cos(direction_1 - phi);
                new_yspeed_1 = magnitude_1 * Math.sin(direction_1 - phi);

                new_xspeed_2 = magnitude_2 * Math.cos(direction_2 - phi);
                new_yspeed_2 = magnitude_2 * Math.sin(direction_2 - phi);

                final_xspeed_1 = ((ballArray[i].mass - ballArray[j].mass) * new_xspeed_1 + (ballArray[j].mass + ballArray[j].mass) * new_xspeed_2) / (ballArray[i].mass + ballArray[j].mass);
                final_xspeed_2 = ((ballArray[i].mass + ballArray[i].mass) * new_xspeed_1 + (ballArray[j].mass - ballArray[i].mass) * new_xspeed_2) / (ballArray[i].mass + ballArray[j].mass);

                final_yspeed_1 = new_yspeed_1;
                final_yspeed_2 = new_yspeed_2;

                ballArray[i].vx = Math.cos(phi) * final_xspeed_1 + Math.cos(phi + Math.PI / 2) * final_yspeed_1;
                ballArray[i].vy = Math.sin(phi) * final_xspeed_1 + Math.sin(phi + Math.PI / 2) * final_yspeed_1;
                ballArray[j].vx = Math.cos(phi) * final_xspeed_2 + Math.cos(phi + Math.PI / 2) * final_yspeed_2;
                ballArray[j].vy = Math.sin(phi) * final_xspeed_2 + Math.sin(phi + Math.PI / 2) * final_yspeed_2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```