# Ball to Ball Collision

Tags: physics, collision-detection, billiards

I read the page [Ball to Ball Collision - Detection and Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345838/ball-to-ball-collision-detection-and-handling) and am a bit confused about the code for resolve_collision. I get everything except what is 1.0f + Constants.restitution? What is 1.0f and what is Constants.restitution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `1.0f` is the literal for a floating point `1.0`. In Java, `1.0` will default to type `double`, so the author is explicitly making it a `float` by adding the `f` flag afterwards.

`Constants.restitution` supposedly represents the [coefficient of restitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_restitution), which is usually an ***e*** or ***C<sub>r</sub>*** in physics. This defines how much a ball bounces once it hits the floor or another ball. Though he doesn't show it in the code he provided, it is probably declared somewhere as

```
public class Constants {
    public static final float restitution = 0.8f;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The coefficient of restitution is a number between 0 and 1 that indicates the amount of elasticity in the collision. A 0 means the contacting bodies will stick together, and a 1 means they will bounce off in a perfectly elastic fashion (recovering all their speed).

Try Googling coefficient of restitution and  the rest will follow.

Comment: What is 1.0f? Is it the same as 1.0 but it's a float?