# problem with collision of two images

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, animation, uiimageview, collision-detection

Well here is my problem:
I have two images : flakeImage and ViewToRotate. What I want is that if flakeImage touches ViewToRotate, ViewToRotate.alpha=0.5; but when FlakeImage appears on the screen ViewToRotate.alpha=0.5; without touching it. I think it's a problem with my view beacause I have :

```
UIImageView* flakeView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:flakeImage];
```

here is the code :

```
UIImageView* flakeView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:flakeImage];

// use the random() function to randomize up our flake attributes
int startY = round(random() % 320);

// set the flake start position
flakeView.center = CGPointMake(490, startY);
flakeView.alpha = 1;

// put the flake in our main view
[self.view addSubview:flakeView];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:flakeView];
// set up how fast the flake will fall
[UIView setAnimationDuration:7 ];

// set the postion where flake will move to
flakeView.center = viewToRotate.center;

// set a stop callback so we can cleanup the flake when it reaches the
// end of its animation
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

How can I solve this please ?
if someone could help me it would be very cool.

Comment: Would it be enough to set the alpha to 0.5 when the animation ends? Or do you need real collision code?

Comment: I need real collision code but when the image(flakeView) appears on the screen without colliding the other is.alpha=0.5;

Comment: Hmm I am still not sure what do you really need. So you've got a flake, a snow flake maybe? And it starts at a random height(startY) and falls down, or well go to the point where viewToRotate is, right? So why do you need collision detection when the goal of the animation is to have the flake be at the same position of the other view? So far it's about position, what does the alpha has to do with it? When the flake hits its final destination it should turn half transparent? Please help me understand.

Comment: no because viewToRotate is a head of a man and what I want is that the flake touches the mouth, because the animation make flake goes to the center of the head, and he doesn't stop until it has reaches the center. What I want is just to : if collide viewToRotate and flake (do something).How can I do this please .Help me

Comment: @arvin Arabi I am sorry, I really don't get it what you like to achieve. Had to remove my answer. Maybe some drawings or some screenshots will help.

Comment: your leaking the variable flakeView. After [UIView commitAnimations], you should add [flakeView release];

Comment: How is checkCollision called and what is viewToRotate?  Are there any transforms on any views?

Comment: @arvin - This is not how Stack Overflow works.  If you don't get a good response to your original question, edit it to make the question clearer.  Reposting of questions is not acceptable, no matter how urgent this is for you.

Comment: ok I won't do it again but there is a reason for this .because no one can respond to this . so can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

CGRect has a intersection function. The frames of UIViews are CGRects.

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(view1.frame, view2.frame) == 1)
  NSLog(@"The views intersect");
else
  NSLog(@"The views do not intersect");
```

The problem I foresee is that if the rects have lots of whitespace, they will appear to intersect before they actually touch

Secondly, you should switch up to block animations. It's strongly encouraged

```
UIImageView* flakeView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:flakeImage] autorelease];

// use the random() function to randomize up our flake attributes
int startY = round(random() % 320);

// set the flake start position
flakeView.center = CGPointMake(490, startY);
flakeView.alpha = 1;

// put the flake in our main view
[self.view addSubview:flakeView];

[UIView animateWithDuration:.7
                 animations:^ {
                         // set the postion where flake will move to
                         flakeView.center = viewToRotate.center;
                  };
```

Did this all from memory, no idea if there are errors.

Circular Collision:

a^2 + b^2 < c^2 means they collide

```
if(pow(view2.frame.origin.x - view1.frame.origin.x, 2) + 
    pow(view2.frame.origin.y - view1.frame.origin.y, 2) < 
    pow(view1.frame.size.width/2, 2))
{
     //collision
}
else
{
     //no collision
}
```

Again, all from memory, check for errors on your own

Comment: that is exactly my problem "they will appear to intersect before they actually touch" how can I solve this ?

Comment: You would have to define custom collision detection for your objects. So instead of rectangular collision, you need circular collision. check edit

Comment: first what is pow it's a variable ? and second instead of //do I have to write CGIntesectsRect... or for exemple do something like view2.alpha =0;

Comment: pow is the mathematical function for exponential math. pow(x, y) = x^y. so pow(2, 3) = 2^3 = 8. Are you trying to keep the view? If you still need the view to be interactable, then you do view2.alpha = 0;. If you don't need the view any more, you can hide it (to use it later: [view2 setHidden:YES];) or release it (done with it, don't need it anymore: [view2 removeFromSuperview];).

Answer (score 0):

I have a bit of sophomoric experience with this, having written http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/balls/id372269039?mt=8. If you check that app out, you will see a bit of the same problem. This topic is a pretty deep rabbit hole. WHen I started that app, I didn't even know how to write a decent game loop. You will need that first because you need to do precise time-step calculations. AFA the collisions, you update your model and view separately, so if you update the model and objects overlap, you need to back them up until they don't collide and then update your view with the result. If you plan to have a lot of colliding objects, you may hit a wall using UIViews. To complicate things more, if your objects are round, CGRectIntersectsRect won't exactly work. That complicates the math a bit, but it's not too bad. With my app, I found it quite difficult to get the physics to look realistic. THe problem became that ball A and B overlap, so you back them up, then they now intersect other balls, etc, etc. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345838/ball-to-ball-collision-detection-and-handling) link is a good starting point, but there are quite a few examples of code out there that "almost" work.