# xcode two images intersects before they actually touch

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation, uiimageview, collision-detection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [problem with collision of two images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926355/problem-with-collision-of-two-images)

HI everyone I'm french so scuse me for my english: SO I have two images(flakeView and viewToRotate) one that is moving, the other static in the center of the screen.What I want is : if flakeView and viewToRotate collide : do something. But the problem is that they intersects before they actually touch and  I don't know where is the problem.
here is the code:

```
UIImageView *flakeView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:flakeImage];

// use the random() function to randomize up our flake attributes
int startX = round(random() % 480);




// set the flake start position
flakeView.center = CGPointMake(startX, -20.0);
flakeView.alpha = 1;

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(startX, -20.0, 30, 30);
flakeView.frame = frame;

// put the flake in our main view
[self.view addSubview:flakeView];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:flakeView];
// set up how fast the flake will fall
[UIView setAnimationDuration:7 ];

// set the postion where flake will move to
flakeView.center = viewToRotate.center;

// set a stop callback so we can cleanup the flake when it reaches the
// end of its animation
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView commitAnimations];
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(flakeView.frame, viewToRotate.frame) == 1){
    //do something
}
```

}

How can I solve this please ?

Comment: Did you check that your images don't have any transparent pixels? (an easy way is to set the background color of the UIView to something). Also you set flakeView.frame = frame but are you sure those are the dimensions of your image ???

Comment: no there is no transparent pixels and yes it is the dimensiions of my image

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that CGRectIntersectsRect is true before the images touch?

If the graphic within the UIImageView is smaller than the frame the UIImageViews will, in fact, touch and even intersect before the visible images touch.  I wonder if that's your problem.

If so, the solution would be to use as much of the frame as possible.

The other condition is that you have a non-rectangular shape inside your UIImageView.  If you have the image of circle then CGRectIntersectsRect can return true when the circles are not touching (but their frames do).

The solution to the above is to either supplement CGRectIntersectsRect with code to check the bounds of the image being portrayed or to create your own collision detection code (my preference) to deal with the unique cases surrounding your shape.

Comment: can we collide the center of an image and the frame of another ?? and if it is possible how can we do this ?

Comment: I think your image view is way to big or.. You have a transparent image...