# Circle collision detection

Tags: java

I have created a program that drawing 2 circle on the screen and using keyboard ASWD and arrow key to move around..here is the code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


class BallObject {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int radius;
BallObject() {
    x=0;
    y=0;
    radius=0;
}

BallObject (int x,int y,int radius) {
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.radius=radius;
}
public void setX(int x) {this.x=x;}
public void setY(int y) {this.y=y;}
public void setRadius(int r) {radius=r;}

public int getX() {return x;}
public int getY() {return y;}
public int getRadius() {return radius;}

}

class Ball extends JFrame implements KeyListener {
 BallObject ball1;
 BallObject ball2;

Ball() {
    super("Simple Ball");

    setSize(800,600); //set screen resolution
    ball1 = new BallObject(getWidth()/2,getHeight()/2,20);
    ball2 = new BallObject(40,40,20);
    addKeyListener(this);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

    g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g2d.fill(new Rectangle(0,0,800,600));

    //drawing ball1
    g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2d.fillOval(ball1.getX(),ball1.getY(),ball1.getRadius()*2,ball1.getRadius()*2);
    //drawing ball2
    g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g2d.fillOval(ball2.getX(),ball2.getY(),ball2.getRadius()*2,ball2.getRadius()*2);
}

public static void main (String args[]) {
   new Ball();
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        ball1.setX(ball1.getX()-2);

    if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        ball1.setX(ball1.getX()+2);

    if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        ball1.setY(ball1.getY()-2);

    if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
        ball1.setY(ball1.getY()+2);


    if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_A){
            ball2.setX(ball2.getX()-2);
            //System.out.println("Hello");
    }


    if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_D)
        ball2.setX(ball2.getX()+2);

    if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_W)
        ball2.setY(ball2.getY()-2);

    if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_S)
        ball2.setY(ball2.getY()+2);


        repaint();
}


            //redraw the screen to show the updated ball location
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}

}
```

Now i need to test the collision..Once two balls are touching each other.it will show a message "COLLISION DETECTED"..pls help...

Comment: Maybe a question for GameDev?

Comment: a ball is not a circle, it's an sphere and the collision formulas are different

Comment: Also you should override `paintComponent` , not `paint` in swing apps.

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345838/ball-to-ball-collision-detection-and-handling

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it simply: if the distance of both center points is less or equal to the sum of the radiuses, then there is a collision?

Comment: @OngPek If you wrote this code yourself, then you can very well calculate the distance between two points and do a comparison. We cannot write your code for you.

Comment: @OngPek Just very simple logical or math operations.

Comment: This coding is my lecturer gave me..he asked me to add collision detection function into it..he just taught me the formula for the collision detection..i do not know how to add into it =(

Comment: I knw the formula to calculate..but i do not know how to apply into java.....pls help =(