# Sphere To Sphere Collisions and Response

Tags: java, game-physics

I am trying to implement some physics on Android. For collision detection I followed this post: [`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345838/ball-to-ball-collision-detection-and-handling.`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345838/ball-to-ball-collision-detection-and-handling) It works just fine, my balls detect collision correctly, but the there is a problem with response. When 2 balls collide, one just flies away with unpredictable velocity. Can somebody please explain me the part where the impulses are calculated?

```
    // collision impulse
float i = (-(1.0f + Constants.restitution) * vn) / (im1 + im2);
Vector2d impulse = mtd.multiply(i);
```

Where is this formula for **i** coming from?  What are the meanings for values **1.0f** and **Contants.restitution** (which is from the authors code : **0.85**). Is there a way to implement this function without using constants like this?

Comment: What do you mean by "Is there a way to implement this function without using constants like this?".

I guess that constant is there for a reason. And `1.0f` is simply an indication that floats are used.

You should provide more code.

Comment: Then, what is the reason? Why he adds 1.0 to Contsants.restitution? The whole function is provided in the link I have given.

Comment: If this is whole method, what are `im1` and `im2` and where they are used?

Why he adds 1.0 to Contsants.restitution? To be able to change it some day. Then if you wish the *restitution* to have different value you change it in one place, and it automatically will be changed everywhere else.

Comment: Did you check the link I have provided? The whole function is there.

Comment: I'm extremely sorry, I was looking on your snippet, not the code, and apparently I cannot help you with this matter. I apologize once again and good luck with figuring it out!