# Solving Billiard Shot Impulse Trajectory

Tags: c++, math, physics, bulletphysics, billiards

I'm using bullet to make a pool simulator and need to accurately simulate shots that are humanly possible. To find the impulse to apply to the cue ball I use the locations of the object ball, pocket center and cue ball.

[image: Common shot scenario]
<sub>(source: [poolplayers.com](http://www.poolplayers.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/372-TangentLine-2.jpg))</sub>

In situations where the motion path of the cue ball is similar to the object ball (a hit angle near 180 degrees), everything works fine and the object ball sinks in the pocket. But it seems that the more angular the shot path is, the greater the margin of error is for the impulse I'm generating. I've tried many things to fix this: adjust the ball's collision margin, scaling the world larger, turning off friction and restitution and lots of others but nothing seems to changes this behavior.

Here are the relevant bits of my code:

```
//assume p = pocket center, b = object ball center, c = cue ball center

//first find the position of the ghost ball, ie the target point of collision for the cue ball
btVector3 ghostPos = b+(b-p).normalize()*(2.0f*BALL_RADIUS);

//then use the normal between the ghostball and cue ball as the impulse, scaled by the shots total distance
btVector3 cueImpulse = (ghostPos-c).normalize()*((p.distance(b)+ghostPos.distance(c))*HIT_RATIO);

//finally apply the impulse to the cueball's center of mass (using general form of applyImpulse to later use rel_pos for english
cueBallBody->applyImpulse(cueImpulse,btVector3());
```

Hopefully that's enough info. I've been struggling with this bug for a looong time and now this very large project I've been working on for almost two years is contingent on solving this problem! Even if you don't see what's wrong with my code, but have an alternative strategy for finding the impulse - I would LOVE to hear it because I'm afraid I don't have anymore ideas.

Comment: If the cue is left of center enough to mess up does the object ball always go left (or right) of the hole? Your suggestion that its related to error would suggest it would go randomly to either side. But if it always goes to the same side, something else is going on.

Comment: The larger or smaller the angle is from a straight shot, the farther the object ball veers. And all shots with a larger angle will veer in the same direction, same with smaller angles in the opposite direction.

Comment: Then try moving the angle of the cue a little to the left or right. Move it in ratio with the angle (or the inverse ratio) and move left or right depending on the side of the ball on which the cue ball lies. See if you can find a small adjustment that fixes it.

Comment: That's a good idea and worth a try! After some reading last night though I have a sneaking suspicion that this has something to do with the local and world spaces. applyImpulse uses world space for the impulse but maybe my calculation is relative to the specific system of the 2 balls and target pocket? Nevertheless I'll try your workaround and let you know, really appreciate the help, I've asked this in 5 different forums and you're the only person whose answered me!

Comment: Did you check out http://archive.ncsa.illinois.edu/Classes/MATH198/townsend/math.html ?

Comment: You haven't shown the dynamics that happen after you apply the impulse to cue ball and it gets collided with the object ball. Are you sure that part is correct?

Comment: Bullet, like nearly every game-oriented physics engine, uses fixed timesteps; it could simply be there's too much penetration in the extreme cases. Did you check to see if the penetration depth is correlated with the errors? Alternatively, if you decrease the size of the `fixedTimeStep` parameter by 10 fold, does the error decrease? Collisions with large tangential relative velocity would amplify the error caused by the time discretization more than head-on collisions, so it fits your description.

Comment: @DanielKO I thought for the longest it was due to a timestep issue but have tried fixedTimeStep's of 1/300 and 1/600 and it still produces this problem.

Comment: @Abhishek Bansal Well the dynamics after applying the impulse are handled by Bullet so it's out of my hands at that point. The problem has something to do with applyImpulse (and the parameters passed to it).

Comment: @Gene Yes I have seen that great page and its become my bible for rolling my own physics implementation now. But it does not cover my issue here or a lot of details that still need to be worked out for a complete simulation (like cue angle and rotation) which are haaaard!

Comment: Try using `applyCentralImpulse(..)` instead, just to see what happens.  Does this change the behavior/error at all?

Comment: @RBarryYoung Tried it, but it has the same outcome.

Comment: Is it possible that the balls (Cue and Object) are not rigid enough?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do complex physics that include rotation of the ball, then I recommend Billiards type of physics:

Example:

http://www.real-world-physics-problems.com/physics-of-billiards.html

http://archive.ncsa.illinois.edu/Classes/MATH198/townsend/math.html

If you want simpler physics I recommend rather "Ball to Ball Collision" for 2D or "Sphere to Sphere collision" for 3D. A quick search in Google, you will find a lot of examples of how to implement it.

Examples:

http://www.hoomanr.com/Demos/Elastic2/

[Ball to Ball Collision - Detection and Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345838/ball-to-ball-collision-detection-and-handling)

Time:

I recommend calculating the timestamp the collision occurred. Calculate all your physics to that time point (pre-collision). That will be your ghostball position. Calculate the collision, including the new speeds of the balls. Then then calculate all your physics for the rest of the time period (post-collision).

Direction:

What you describe actually make sense (physics wise) for me. If the ball is moving upwards (if you look at your diagram), then the transfer of momentum will be more upwards, and you have to do a small compensation in direction for it. The correct way is to write out the formula for the 2D speed at collision and position with the direction, and work it out that way.

Update:
Easy way: Rotate the ghost ball around the colliding ball in the opposite direction of the error, the degrees to rotate it is relative to the degrees in fault / distance.

Comment: These are good suggestions on writing my own physics implementation and I've already used "real-world-physics" as a reference, very definitive article! But I can't mark this as a solution because I was asking how to fix my bullet physics problem. Sorry! But thanks for the good info.

Comment: I understand and you are welcome. I try to help where I can. My experience is that you need to understand the underlying physics and math to implement a realistic looking physics simulation. The nice thing about physics is that if you do it without "hacks", it will handle everything you throw at it by itself. Good luck and enjoy.

Comment: I don't know if you noticed it, but I made an update to the solution. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Visually, it looks like you're not accounting for the energy that goes into the cue ball and stays with the cueball afterwards.

Things to check:

1. What does the error look like: is it random or is the answer just wrong?

   - If you add random small values to the inputs, what happens?
   - If you do a point plot through various angles, what does the trend line look like?
   - If you do a point plot thought various distances, what is the trend?
2. Significant digits

   - Google tells me that `btVector3` can use floats or doubles.  Floats have ~24 binary digits of precision and it's scary to see how quickly they can lose significant digits.  (Possibly inside normalize?) Have you tried using doubles?
   - Are you using numbers of different scale?  When you get to extreme angles, you may see x-coordinates or x-offsets get near zero and do to scaling they may get lost in the floating point arithmetic.  Also happens if you subtract two numbers that are almost exactly the same.

Best of luck.