# Images collision without images colliding upon reset

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Just a quick issue when my app reloads two images collide without actually touching. I have reset the frames of these images to their original positioning i did as follows:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

redball.frame = CGRectMake(redballpos.x, redballpos.y, redball.frame.size.width, redball.frame.size.height); //makes frame
ball1.frame = CGRectMake(ball1pos.x, ball1pos.y, ball1.frame.size.width, ball1.frame.size.height);
ball2.frame = CGRectMake(ball2pos.x, ball2pos.y, ball2.frame.size.width, ball2.frame.size.height);


}
```

and my original ViewDidload is as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

redballpos = redball.frame.origin;
ball1pos = ball1.frame.origin;
ball2pos = ball2.frame.origin;
exit.hidden = YES;
ball2.hidden = YES;
highScore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"HighScoreSaved"];
adView.delegate = self;


[super viewDidLoad];

}
```

Would anyone know what i am doing wrong?
All advice would be much appreciated

Comment: For one, You should call the [super viewDidLoad]; before anything else. Second, there is no [super viewWillAppear:animated] in your code. Last but not least for collision detection between rects you could probably use the CGRectIntersectsRect function?

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345838/ball-to-ball-collision-detection-and-handling?rq=1

Comment: I see. Its just its almost like the game vc does not reload when the game ends. What is the best way to refresh a Vc when a game ends?

Comment: http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/102221-reset-a-uiviewcontroller-to-its-initial-view.html

Comment: For more audience and reach always use proper tags!!!