# HTML5 canvas random directions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Using HTML5 canvas where would be the best place to start to move my 3 balls in random trajectories (along a smooth line, no jumping) and when they hit each other bounce away and then go on another path, until again they hit each other and again bounce away.

So far I have set up a simple example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3tfUN/2)  where each ball follows its own path (though they do disappear off the screen).

At the moment the trajectory is as simple as

```
function animate(){

  // Yellow Circle
  circles[0].x+=1;
  circles[0].y+=-1.5;

  // Blue Cirlce
  circles[1].x+=-1;
  circles[1].y+=-1.5;

  // Red Circle
  circles[2].x+=1;
  circles[2].y+=-1;
  draw();

 }
```

I would love to see an example, but also to know what methods and calculations I should be looking at.

Comment: This is not a S.O. question. Search for tutorials on the web, rather.

Comment: As far as the random trajectories go, it seems as simple as setting your x and y components to a random float within some range, determined by yourself as preferred. Am I wrong?

Comment: ok taking that on board i have updated the fiddle, but the behaviour of the yellow ball is too random, when the ball moves it needs to move in incremental movements

Answer (score 5):

This code is created by Adam Brookes for adambrookesprojects.co.uk on 06/10/2013.

Moving the balls

```
    function updateBallPos(deltaTime, ballArray) {
        for (var i = 0; i < ballArray.length; i++) {
            ballArray[i].lastGoodPosition = ballArray[i].position; // save the balls last good position.
            ballArray[i].position = ballArray[i].position.add((ballArray[i].velocity.multiply(deltaTime/10))); // add the balls (velocity * deltaTime) to position. 
        }
    }
```

Detecting Ball collision

```
function checkBallCollision(ball1, ball2) {
        var xDistance = (ball2.getX() - ball1.getX()); 
        var yDistance = (ball2.getY() - ball1.getY());
        var distanceBetween = Math.sqrt((xDistance * xDistance) + (yDistance *yDistance)); 

        var sumOfRadius = ((ball1.getRadius()) + (ball2.getRadius())); // add the balls radius together

        if (distanceBetween < sumOfRadius) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

[SEE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/59jgw/)

All the code are clearly explained by him [HERE](http://www.adambrookesprojects.co.uk/project/canvas-collision-elastic-collision-tutorial/)

[RELATED QUESTION HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345838/ball-to-ball-collision-detection-and-handling)