# Collision Resolution between a circle and a rectangle

Tags: java, swing, awt, physics, collision

Can anyone please help me out with this collision resolution process?
I am colliding a circle with a rectangle and can detect the collision. However, I am at a loss to understand how to resolve the velocities of the two for a general case. In my case, the rectangle is a static, non-rotatable massive target. So, when I collide the circle, I cannot understand what vector components should act along the x and y axis to simulate real world collision. Please help me out. Thank you in advance...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*Ball to Ball Collision—Detection and Handling*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/345838/230513).

Comment: See also [Collision detection with complex shapes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14575043/418556) for a working example.